# Silverlight simulate mouse click by X, Y?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

If there is a way to send mouse click event by location programatically it would be great, but if theres another approach that can solve following problem this it is fine too.

In my situation I got a canvas taking up whole application size (covering it completely) and when user clicks it with mouse I want to hide it, and then pass through this mouse click (taking its location x & y from user) to anything that is under canvas (in my case canvas visibility goes to collapsed so controls under it can be seen now).

I am guessing it is impossible, cause certain features like run silverlight fullscreen can only be done in button click handler (correct me if im wrong here).

But is there a place where I can read about those security based limitations of silverlight UI ?

Comment: Hi. What exactly are you trying to do? Is teh click on the canvas by a user or do you want to simulate this click? Do you want, that the control which is clicked then gets the focus after the canvas has toggled its visible state?

Comment: initial click is by the user, i handle it in usual way, and then want to simulate exact same click on my application again (it will be handled differently since user click changed its view)

Comment: Ok, sry but I have to ask again. The user clicks on the canvas and then you want a click on the undelying control. E.g. if the user clicks on the canvas and underlying the click coordinates is a TextBox, the TextBox should be focused?

Comment: yes, that is the expected behaviour for textbox if it happens to be under the point where user clicks on canvas

Answer (score 0):

you have to [add an click event handler to your canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). In this handler you get the x and y positon of your click (via [MouseButtonEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.aspx)) and then you can use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to get your "hit elements".

Lets assume the following xaml:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button  Width="50" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox Text="MyText" Width="200" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Canvas Background="Red"  x:Name="MyCanvas"  />
    </Grid>
```

with the following code behind:

```
    public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                MyCanvas.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(handler), true);
            }

            void handler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                var point = new Point(e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
                var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(point, this);
                foreach (var uiElement in elements)
                {
                    if (uiElement is TextBox){
                      ((TextBox) uiElement).Focus();
                      break;
                    }
                    if(uiElement is Button)
                    {
                      //do button stuff here
                      break;
                    }
                }
                MyCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MyCanvas.RemoveHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(handler));
            }
```

But: In this simple example, you get at about 20 hit elements. But they are sorted in the correct "z-Index". So you can iterate through it and the first interesting element for you is where you could break(Maybe you can do this with LINQ, too). So for me, I know that the first hit TextBox is what I want to focus.

Is this what you need?

BR,

TJ

Comment: thanks for the reply, however you provide a specific approach for textBox , I need to pass this click event (or mousedown & up  combination of events) to the first underlying by Z index control under my canvas. So if we take your approach that would require UIElement to have a single method we can call for any elements to handle mouse click event.

Comment: Hi, see my edit. You would have several if clauses.The first clause which is true breaks the loop. If you want to execute the Button you have several opps. If you use commands you can get the command and the command param from the button object and execute it. If you have the click handler in your class, you can just call the click handler. If you need an MouseDown event you can attach it, too.(MyCanvas.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, ...)

Comment: thanks for reply, however this isnt a generic approach, Imagine that my application changes and this logic has to be preserved, whenever I add new items I have to introduce more ifs. It could be a simple bruteforce solution if application consisted of several usercontrols but not for my or more general case